# Can Nearby message API be used on wear OS device?

Tags: android, wear-os, google-nearby

I need to find the distance between my wear watch & android phone for that I planned to use [Nearby API](https://developers.google.com/nearby/messages/android/get-started), I plan to use `MessageListener` class `onDistanceChanged(Message message, Distance distance)` method callback. Which returns `distance` object with meters information in it.

I added a dependency to nearby play service to my wear application I get following error:

```
E/GmsClient: unable to connect to service: com.google.android.gms.nearby.messages.service.NearbyMessagesService.START on com.google.android.gms
```

I looked into details of this API they say to run this API it needs Wi-fi, Bluetooth, Audio hardware. On my wear device, there is no Wifi adapter.

Does Nearby API work on wear?

Comment: the api needs those 3 things because it probably uses them all to triangulate your location so if it says it needs the 3 my bet is it won't work